# Ubuntu doesn't boot after install

Tags: boot

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my computer, everything worked properly until i install update packages, Ubuntu won't boot after restart, my screen goes blank. I've reinstalled Ubuntu twice and now for the third time Ubuntu won't even boot after installation...?!

I run a medion computer, p4 2.4ghz dual
1gb memory, 256mb geforce 6200, 250gb HDD. (Sata)

What can i do? Somebody help please because there's no way I'm going to run windows again!

EDIT:
Found the problem for not booting after installation, I've chosen to install updates during installation, so running installation again right now without updates, but still don't understand why updates from Ubuntu would cause it not to boot? Should i not run updates at all?

Comment: Sounds like a coincidental hardware problem. I'd recommend troubleshooting your hardware components. In any case, I doubt this is the correct forum for this.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a black screen of death you're talking about, then according to Nixie Pixel's video on this, it's the fact that you have an Intel graphics card. You're going to want to go watch her video at youtube.com/nixiedoeslinux, and search for black screen of death.